# Loop Through Userform & Paste to Offset Cells

Tags: vba, for-loop, controls, each, userform

It's me again!

I am trying to input data into a database with a userform by looping through each control and pasting it into a cell via an offset with a counter. I am getting an error on the line which actually inputs the data to the cell and cannot figure out how to do this via a loop. It would be easy to do it field by field but I do not want to write that many lines of code.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cbSubmit_Click()
' Set worksheet
Dim dbFood As Worksheet
Set dbFood = Sheets("dbFood")

'Set last row and column
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim lCol As Long
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Row

'Define idCell as Range type
Dim idCell As Range

' If no records exit, add first record
If Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "ID" Then
    Set idCell = dbFood.Range("A2")
    idCell.Value = 1

' Add Data
Dim ufControl As Control
Dim Counter As Long
Counter = 1

For Each ufControl In Me.Controls

If TypeOf ufControl Is MSForms.ComboBox Or MSForms.TextBox Then
idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufField.Value
Counter = Counter + 1

End If

Next ufControl

MsgBox "Added to database!"

' Else add next record
ElseIf Cells(lRow, 1).Value >= 0.1 Then
    Dim lastID As Long
    lastID = Cells(lRow, 1).Value

    Set idCell = dbFood.Cells(lRow + 1, 1)
    idCell.Value = lastID + 1

' Add Data


' If none of the above display ERROR and exit sub
Else: MsgBox ("ERROR - Cannot Create Record")
Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to solve this one then great!

Comment: why did you call it ufField.Value when it would be ufControl.value? (after if TypeOf ufControl IS....)

Comment: Ah that was the old naming convention I gave it but ufControl made a bit more sense so I changed it. Thanks for spotting that one. However the error probably lies within the method I am trying to use to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some things that I have adapted down below. May I ask you to test that bit of code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub cbSubmit_Click()

    Dim dbFood As Worksheet
    Set dbFood = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("dbFood")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = dbFood.Cells(dbFood.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = dbFood.Cells(1, dbFood.Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Row

    Dim idCell As Range


    If dbFood.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "ID" Then
        Set idCell = dbFood.Range("A2")
        idCell.Value = 1

        Dim ufControl As Control
        Dim Counter As Long
        Counter = 1

        For Each ufControl In Me.Controls

            If TypeOf ufControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufControl.Result
                Counter = Counter + 1
            ElseIF TypeOf ufControl Is MSForms.ComboBox
                idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufControl.SeletedItem.Value
            End If

       Next ufControl

       MsgBox "Added to database!"

    ElseIf dbFood.Cells(lRow, 1).Value >= 0.1 Then
        Dim lastID As Long
        lastID = dbFood.Cells(lRow, 1).Value

        Set idCell = dbFood.Cells(lRow + 1, 1)
        idCell.Value = lastID + 1

    Else
        MsgBox ("ERROR - Cannot Create Record")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see I have divided the types of the ufcontrol as I am not sure that with a combobox you can directly say .Value so you'll have to add .SelectedItem. You can at least try it once :)

Comment: This seems to produce:  Run-time Error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method... Been getting this a lot with userforms recently.

This errors on the line:
idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufControl.Result

Comment: change "idCell.Offset(0,Counter).Value" to "idCell.CurrentRegion.Offset(0, Counter).Value" for a sec and see if it still throws the error.

Comment: I have selected your response as the answer because I only had to make a very small change to get it to work. I just changed the .result and .value to .text and that seems to do the trick. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by using the method Kathara suggested to me but edited it to avoid the 438 error. Below is the small adjustment I made to make it work:

```
For Each ufControl In Me.Controls

        If TypeOf ufControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufControl.Text
            Counter = Counter + 1
        ElseIf TypeOf ufControl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            idCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = ufControl.Text
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If

    Next ufControl
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: hahaha ok I didn't think this would give the error, but really happy that I could help you figuring out how to make it work ;)